# How can I save only those rows from a DataFrame which columns have values from the list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame loaded from a `pr2` CSV:
[the DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev18Y.png)

And I have a list `costs_pr2`:
[the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRWwQ.png)

I wanted to save only rows that have values from `costs_pr2` in a "costs" column.

I tried this:

```py
pr2 = pr2[~pr2.costs.isin(costs_pr2)]
```

But nothing has changed  in `pr2`.
What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `query` to achieve your goal:

```
costs_pr2 = ['a','b','c']
new_dataframe = pr2.query("costs in @costs_pr2",inplace=False)
```

Otherwise you could directly:

```
pr2.query("costs in @costs_pr2",inplace=True)
```

Comment: What is the "costs"? An int or a string?

Comment: I wanted to add that there may the case that, for string values, you would need to add an additional quotation like: df.query('col == "val"')